# Windows Phone - Poor encryption performance

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, encryption, aes

I have used following code for encryption in Windows Phone:

```
public static string Encrypt(string dataToEncrypt, string password)
{
AesManaged aes = null;
MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;
string salt = "12345678";

try
{
    // Generate a Key based on a Password and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator
    // Salt must be at least 8 bytes long
    // Use an iteration count of at least 1000
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), 10000);

    // Create AES algorithm
    aes = new AesManaged();

    // Key derived from byte array with 32 pseudo-random key bytes
    aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(32);

    // IV derived from byte array with 16 pseudo-random key bytes
    aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);

    // Create Memory and Crypto Streams
    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Encrypt Data
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Return Base 64 String
    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
finally
{
    if (cryptoStream != null)
    {
        cryptoStream.Close();
    }

    if (memoryStream != null)
    {
        memoryStream.Close();
    }

    if (aes != null)
    {
        aes.Clear();
    }
}
}

public static string Decrypt(string dataToDecrypt, string password)
{
AesManaged aes = null;
MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
string salt = "12345678";

try
{
    // Generate a Key based on a Password and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator
    // Salt must be at least 8 bytes long
    // Use an iteration count of at least 1000
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), 10000);

    // Create AES algorithm
    aes = new AesManaged();

    // Key derived from byte array with 32 pseudo-random key bytes
    aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(32);

    // IV derived from byte array with 16 pseudo-random key bytes
    aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);

    // Create Memory and Crypto Streams
    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Decrypt Data
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt);
    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Return Decrypted String
    byte[] decryptBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    // Dispose
    if (cryptoStream != null)
    {
        cryptoStream.Dispose();
    }

    // Retval
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptBytes, 0, decryptBytes.Length);
}
finally
{
    if (memoryStream != null)
    {
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }

    if (aes != null)
    {
        aes.Clear();
    }
}
}
```

The performance of encyrption is very poor. Can anyone suggest some improvement on above code?

Comment: How poor is the performance?  Where?  You should realize that a few hundred milliseconds should be acceptable considering that you're iterating a hash for precisely that reason.

Comment: The processing without encryption used to completed in 5-6 seconds. After encryption it takes 25-30 seconds. I am encrypted JSON string which is very small in size.

Comment: If you're not using this to exchange between a web-server, here's two pretty good WP7 encryption libraries you can use (although one focuses specifically on IsolatedStorage) http://encryptedzoology.blogspot.com/2011/01/usability-and-cryptography.html
 

http://scrypt.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I am using this to exchange between my device and web-server (asp.net 4.0).

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could move the key derivation code using Rfc2898DeriveBytes outside of those function since the key for a given password will be constant and will be usually used multiple times. Other than that I don't see much room for improvement.

Comment: I don't understand exactly. Each time there will be different password. How can it be used used multiple time?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should introduce some using() brackets to make sure there are no memory leaks. You could have a look at this:

http://zayko.net/post/How-to-EncryptDecrypt-a-String-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

This would only help if your function became slower over time, instead on the first run.